# How to iterate Json List data in angular 6

Tags: angular

I have below response which i am getting from one of my service.
response i can see in console but not able to iterate.

```
{
    "input": {
        "personId": "0519769867"
    },
    "output": {
        "error": null,
        "customerName": "ANDERSON, JACQUELINE",
        "customerRole": "P",
        "customerEmail": "test.1@gmail.com",
        "contactNumber": "(789) 989-0001",
        "accountList": [
            {
                "accountInfo": {
                    "accountId": "9444378190",
                    "currentBalance": null,
                    "payoffBalance": null,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "serviceAgreements": [
                        {
                            "serviceInfo": {
                                "saId": "9445462369",
                                "saStatus": "10",
                                "serviceType": "WATER",
                                "saStartDt": "2018-09-11",
                                "saEndDt": "2019-01-24"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "dateTimeTagFormat": "xsd:strict"
}



this._freeapiservice.getPostComments(opost).subscribe((response:Response)=>{

 this.respnseData = Object.keys(response);
 for (const key in response) {
        if (this.respnseData[key] == 'output' ){      
             console.log("response data for output  "+this.respnseData[key]);
  }   
}
```

i want to take all individual data from output key and populate on ui

Answer (score 0):

You can print the `output` key simply by:

```
this._freeapiservice.getPostComments(opost).subscribe((response: Response) => {
  console.log("response data for output  " + response.output);
})
```